# Possible risk with too extensive session time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm running an ASP.NET 4.0 application on IIS 7.5. My customer want to use the application like desktop application and don't want to log in every 20 mins (after inactivity). My customer want session to be set to 8 hours, only log in to the application in the morning and log out when they leave office. My question is, what kind of risk is related to that (performance, security). The application doesnt have a high workload and at most there will be 30 users logged in at the same time. I couldn't really find any information about this.

Follow up question... if there are no risk the place to make my changes are the following?

```
<forms name="x" loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="480" path="/" />
<sessionState timeout="490" />
```

Idle-Time (inactivity) in advanced settings for my application pool.

Have i missed anything?

Comment: Is this running on an internal network? Perhaps use windows authentication? Sessions are kept short but authentication occurs behind the scenes

Comment: @Liath. This is running on the web.